# Implementation of Enum.TryParse in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net

How could I implement the .NET 4's Enum.TryParse method in .NET 3.5?

```cs
public static bool TryParse<TEnum>(string value, out TEnum result) where TEnum : struct
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Took longer than I hoped to get this right, but it works and has been tested. Hope this saves someone some time!

```
    private static readonly char[] FlagDelimiter = new [] { ',' };

    public static bool TryParseEnum<TEnum>(string value, out TEnum result) where TEnum : struct {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
            result = default(TEnum);
            return false;
        }

        var enumType = typeof(TEnum);

        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type '{0}' is not an enum", enumType.FullName));


        result = default(TEnum);

        // Try to parse the value directly 
        if (Enum.IsDefined(enumType, value)) {
            result = (TEnum)Enum.Parse(enumType, value);
            return true;
        }

        // Get some info on enum
        var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
        if (enumValues.Length == 0)
            return false;  // probably can't happen as you cant define empty enum?
        var enumTypeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(enumValues.GetValue(0).GetType());

        // Try to parse it as a flag 
        if (value.IndexOf(',') != -1) {
            if (!Attribute.IsDefined(enumType, typeof(FlagsAttribute)))
                return false;  // value has flags but enum is not flags

            // todo: cache this for efficiency
            var enumInfo = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var enumNames = Enum.GetNames(enumType);
            for (var i = 0; i < enumNames.Length; i++)
                enumInfo.Add(enumNames[i], enumValues.GetValue(i));

            ulong retVal = 0;
            foreach(var name in value.Split(FlagDelimiter)) {
                var trimmedName = name.Trim();
                if (!enumInfo.ContainsKey(trimmedName))
                    return false;   // Enum has no such flag

                var enumValueObject = enumInfo[trimmedName];
                ulong enumValueLong;
                switch (enumTypeCode) {
                    case TypeCode.Byte:
                        enumValueLong = (byte)enumValueObject;
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.SByte:
                        enumValueLong = (byte)((sbyte)enumValueObject);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.Int16:
                        enumValueLong = (ushort)((short)enumValueObject);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.Int32:
                        enumValueLong = (uint)((int)enumValueObject);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.Int64:
                        enumValueLong = (ulong)((long)enumValueObject);
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.UInt16:
                        enumValueLong = (ushort)enumValueObject;
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.UInt32:
                        enumValueLong = (uint)enumValueObject;
                        break;
                    case TypeCode.UInt64:
                        enumValueLong = (ulong)enumValueObject;
                        break;
                    default:
                        return false;   // should never happen
                }
                retVal |= enumValueLong;
            }
            result = (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(enumType, retVal);
            return true;
        }

        // the value may be a number, so parse it directly
        switch (enumTypeCode) {
            case TypeCode.SByte:
                sbyte sb;
                if (!SByte.TryParse(value, out sb))
                    return false;
                result = (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(enumType, sb);
                break;
            case TypeCode.Byte:
                byte b;
                if (!Byte.TryParse(value, out b))
                    return false;
                result = (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(enumType, b);
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int16:
                short i16;
                if (!Int16.TryParse(value, out i16))
                    return false;
                result = (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(enumType, i16);
                break;
            case TypeCode.UInt16:
                ushort u16;
                if (!UInt16.TryParse(value, out u16))
                    return false;
                result = (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(enumType, u16);
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                int i32;
                if (!Int32.TryParse(value, out i32))
                    return false;
                result = (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(enumType, i32);
                break;
            case TypeCode.UInt32:
                uint u32;
                if (!UInt32.TryParse(value, out u32))
                    return false;
                result = (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(enumType, u32);
                break;
            case TypeCode.Int64:
                long i64;
                if (!Int64.TryParse(value, out i64))
                    return false;
                result = (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(enumType, i64);
                break;
            case TypeCode.UInt64:
                ulong u64;
                if (!UInt64.TryParse(value, out u64))
                    return false;
                result = (TEnum)Enum.ToObject(enumType, u64);
                break;
            default:
                return false; // should never happen
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You can change those switch statements into reflection instead of listing all types possible and shorten the code.

Comment: @NickTurner: performance is important for this method, reflection is not good for performance.

Comment: note: the `Enum.Tryparse` in .net 4+ won't throw these exceptions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Julian: removed the first exception, kept the second one since docs indicate it is thrown. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 15):

I dislike using a `try-catch` to handle any conversion failures or other non-exceptional events as part of the normal flow of my application, so my own `Enum.TryParse` method for .NET 3.5 and earlier makes use of the `Enum.IsDefined()` method to make sure the there will not be an exception thrown by Enum.Parse().  You can also include some null checks on `value` to prevent an `ArgumentNullException` if value is null.

```
public static bool TryParse<TEnum>(string value, out TEnum result)
    where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    var retValue = value == null ? 
                false : 
                Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), value);
    result = retValue ?
                (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), value) :
                default(TEnum);
    return retValue;
}
```

Obviously this method will not reside in the `Enum` class so you will need a class to include this in that would be appropriate.

One limitation is the lack of an `enum` constraint on generic methods, so you would have to consider how you want to handle incorrect types.  `Enum.IsDefined` will throw an `ArgumentException` if `TEnum` is not an `enum` but the only other option is a runtime check and throwing a different exception, so I generally do not add an additional check and just let the type checking in these methods handle for me.  I'd consider adding `IConvertible` as another constraint, just to help constrain the type even more.

Comment: I like this one better than my approach (now deleted) for sure.

Comment: +1 Agreed, if I would have spent another minute looking at the Enum methods and seen the IsDefined method this is most likely what would have happened. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Whilst it was a good start, there's quite a few other considerations to make it on par with .NET 4's implementation (e.g. value as comma separated flags, value as number, enum numeric type)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with [Flags] enum combinations.

Comment: @ZverevEvgeniy been so long since I wrote this, I can't remember if i tried it with the [Flags]

Answer (score 3):

It won't be a static method on Enum (static extension methods don't quite make sense), but it should work

```
public static class EnumHelpers
{
    public static bool TryParse<TEnum>(string value, out TEnum result)
        where TEnum : struct
    {
        try
        {
            result = (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), value); 
        }
        catch
        {
            result = default;
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog) we also needed `Enum.TryParse` for .Net 3.5. We have implemented the basic features (just parse, case sensitive and insensitive, no flags) influenced by this post.

This basic implementation is highly unit tested so it has the same behavior as Microsoft`s .Net 4 implementation.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Enum.TryParse implementation for .net 3.5 
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <remarks>Don't uses reflection</remarks>
// ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Local
private static bool TryParseEnum_net3<TEnum>(string value, bool ignoreCase, out TEnum result) where TEnum : struct
{
    var enumType = typeof(TEnum);
    if (!enumType.IsEnum())
        throw new ArgumentException($"Type '{enumType.FullName}' is not an enum");

    if (StringHelpers.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
        result = default(TEnum);
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        result = (TEnum)Enum.Parse(enumType, value, ignoreCase);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        result = default(TEnum);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And is using:

```cs
public static class StringHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// IsNullOrWhiteSpace, including for .NET 3.5
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [ContractAnnotation("value:null => true")]
    internal static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string value)
    {
#if NET3_5

        if (value == null) return true;
        if (value.Length == 0) return true;
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Trim());
#else
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value);
#endif
    }
}
```

The code can be found at [the NLog GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/ceb6018b6449e83e76f4907040d903baa3fe7b7f/src/NLog/Common/ConversionHelpers.cs), and also the [unit tests are on GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/ceb6018b6449e83e76f4907040d903baa3fe7b7f/tests/NLog.UnitTests/Internal/ConversionHelpersTests.cs)  (xUnit)