# Value of a String to e.KeyCode in C#

Tags: c#, keycode

So im in C# Windows Form Application in Visual Studio, Im making a soundboard program that plays sounds to corresponding "Hotkeys" that are set by the user. Im having trouble figuring out how to get the program to recognise the user set hotkeys. That might sound vague, so let me show you.

Ok, this is the code that is set to run from the start "What you edit when you double click the form in the design menu"

```
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)

    {
     // The Program plays sound
    }
```

So I know that when I press "d" on my keyboard, the sound plays.

Well, I want the sound to play when I type in a character that I have written in a textbox somewhere else. So like I open my program put "t" into the  "set hotkey" text box, then press t and the sound plays.

So I want the program do do something like this

```
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.(textBox1.Text)) // textBox1 is my set hotkey box 

    {
     // The Program plays sound
    }
```

Is there some way I can get textBox.Text to be recognised by e.KeyCode?
Do I have to convert textBox1.Text to a key code value?
If so, How?

Im new to coding, so try to explain it to me as if I were a dummy :D

I really appriciate your time!

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898806/how-to-convert-a-character-to-key-code

Comment: are you trying to play sounds for every character in that text box??

Comment: Updated my answer, try it now. I was missing `()` in `ToString()`

Answer (score 5):

Use [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
Keys key;
if (Enum.TryParse<Keys>(textBox1.Text, out key))
{
    //Do something with key
    if (e.KeyCode == key)
    {

    }
}
```

If you're concerned about only 1 character try the following:

```
Keys key;
if (textBox1.TextLength > 0 && Enum.TryParse<Keys>(textBox1.Text[0].ToString(), out key))
{
    //Do something with key
    if (e.KeyCode == key)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: If i put that in, i get red line from "Enum to the end of line. Error reads, "The Best Overloaded Method Match for 'System.enum.tryparse<System.windows.forms.keys>(string, out system.windows.forms.keys)' has some invalid arguements

Comment: @DavidLancaster Am sorry, I can't help you anymore if you don't say what is the error message you get. Also which version of .net you're using?

Comment: I edited for error message. Im using visual studio 2012

Comment: enum.tryparse is only available in .Net framework 4 or above.

Comment: Enum.tryparse expect 3 argument so use                                                                if(Enum.TryParse<Keys>(ch.ToString,true, out key))
 and let me know the result

Comment: Hmm, that must be issue. Is there a method for a lower framwork?

Comment: @DavidLancaster You can implement Tryparse on your own [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017151/implementation-of-enum-tryparse-in-net-3-5)

Comment: Which frame work are you  using..?? you can check it from the properties window of your project.

Comment: says framework 4.5 also, now line uner "e.Keycode" reads "'system.eventArgs' does not contain definition for KeyCode and no extension method 'Keycode' accepting first arguement of type 'system.eventArgs' could be found

Comment: @DavidLancaster `e.KeyCode` is taken from your code. If you don't need, you can ignore it. `key` is the converted value. Use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse the text value as enum.

```
if (e.KeyCode == (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), textBox1.Text))
{
 // The Program plays sound
}
```

(Pseudo code, not complied)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create an [KeyDown event](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7PTEXzXZmY) at your textbox and with an switch staement you can differ between the different keys

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Switch(e.Key)
             case e.Key == Key.D; PlaysondforD; break;
             case e.Key == Key.E; PlaysondforE; break;
             .........
    }
```