# C# - Getting multiple values with a single key, from a text file

Tags: c#, file, dictionary, io

I store multiple values that shares a single key on a text file. The text file looks like that:

```
Brightness 36 , Manual
BacklightCompensation 3 , Manual
ColorEnable 0 , None
Contrast 16 , Manual
Gain 5 , Manual
Gamma 122 , Manual
Hue 0 , Manual
Saturation 100 , Manual
Sharpness 2 , Manual
WhiteBalance 5450 , Auto
```

Now I want to store the int value & string value of each key (Brightness, for example).

New to C# and could'nt find something that worked yet.

Thanks

Comment: Who designed the structure of the text file?

Comment: `Regex.Matches(input, @"((.*) (\d+) , (.*))").Cast<Match>()` sould do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regex and a little bit of linq you can do many things.
Here I assume you Know [How to read a Text file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file).

Pros: If the file is not perfect, the reg exp will just ignore the misformatted line, and won't throw error.

Here is a hardcode version of your file, note that a `\r` will appears because of it. Depending on the way you read you file but it should not be the case with a `File.ReadLines()`

```
string input =
@"Brightness 36 , Manual
BacklightCompensation 3 , Manual
ColorEnable 0 , None
Contrast 16 , Manual
Gain 5 , Manual
Gamma 122 , Manual
Hue 0 , Manual
Saturation 100 , Manual
Sharpness 2 , Manual
WhiteBalance 5450 , Auto";

string regEx = @"(.*) (\d+) , (.*)";

var RegexMatch = Regex.Matches(input, regEx).Cast<Match>();

var outputlist = RegexMatch.Select(x => new { setting = x.Groups[1].Value
                                              , value = x.Groups[2].Value
                                              , mode  = x.Groups[3].Value });
```

#### Regex explanation:`/(.*) (\d+) , (.*)/g`

**1st Capturing Group (.*)**
  `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 matches the character  literally (case sensitive)

**2nd Capturing Group (\d+)**
`\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 `,`  matches the characters `,`  literally (case sensitive)

**3rd Capturing Group (.*)**
`.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
`*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

#### Disclamer:

Never trust an input! Even if it's a file some other program did, or send by a customer.

From my experience, you have then two ways of handeling bad format:
Read line by line, and register every bad line.
or Ignore them. You don't fit , you don't sit!

And don't tell your self it won't happend, it will!

Comment: Every text file is created first from code, so the input should be safe.
I understand that i need to use "File.ReadAllText" to get it as a string and not as an array,
but i'm not sure how to get the values out? How do i reach "setting", "value", "mode"?

Comment: `foreach (var ff in outputlist) { 
                ff.Field
            }` if you need foreach or `var ff = outputlist.Where(x => x.Name = "foo").Single().Name;` if looking for a specific value

Comment: It should behave like Tim solution except it's an anonymous type.

Comment: Will update this answer with an other version, tomorow.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to use custom types to store these settings like these:

```
public enum DisplaySettingType
{
    Manual, Auto, None
}

public class DisplaySetting
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public DisplaySettingType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could use following LINQ query using `string.Split` to get all settings:

```
decimal value = 0;
DisplaySettingType type = DisplaySettingType.None;

IEnumerable<DisplaySetting> settings = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(l => l.Trim().Split(new[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Where(arr => arr.Length >= 3 && decimal.TryParse(arr[1], out value) && Enum.TryParse(arr[2], out type))
    .Select(arr => new DisplaySetting { Name = arr[0], Value = value, Type = type });
```

Comment: @AaYy May you give us more information about the error? 5$ on a path error.

Comment: "No definition for ReadLine", changed to ReadAllLine.
"No Definition for TryParse", changed to Parse.
"Argument 1 cannot convert from 'string' to 'System type'"
"Argument 2 may not be passed with the 'out' word"

Comment: @AaYy: [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) is a method that was introduced with .NET 4. It enables to start processing the lines before all lines were read into memory (like `ReadAllLines`). The same applies to `Enum.TryParse`, it was introduced with .NET 4. You can create your own `TryParse`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017151/implementation-of-enum-tryparse-in-net-3-5